# What castle is this?

Tags: europe, identify-this, architecture

Can anyone tell me what castle this is and where it is located?

[image: castle]

Comment: Do you have any clues at all -- such as an approximate country? Your image seems to have some text cropped away; what does that say? Where is it from?

Comment: Not getting anything with an image reverse search :(

Comment: I have no idea what country it is in. The text at the top does not go with the picture.

Comment: Found it!  -  Veliki Tabor Castle in Croatia

Comment: @Ruecatt add this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments, it appears to be Veliki Tabor Castle, in Croatia.

[Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veliki_Tabor_Castle)

> Veliki Tabor (Croatian: Great Camp) is a castle and museum in
>   northwest Croatia, dating from the middle of 15th century. The
>   castle's present appearance dates back to the 16th century.
>
> Most of the castle was built by the Hungarian noble family of Ráttkay,
>   in whose ownership it remained until 1793.
>
> It is located in the region of Zagorje near Desinić, 8 km (5.0 mi)
>   west of Pregrada, 334 m (1,096 ft) above sea level. It has around
>   3,340 m2 (36,000 sq ft). The castle is owned by the state, which
>   manages it as a museum and a tourist site.

Comment: The oldest parts of the castle date from the 12th century. The first written mention of it is in Ecclesia sancti Gheorgii de Zothla from 1334. Admittedly, the current state is from the 16th century indeed. Both the [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattkay) and the [Hungarian](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desini%C4%87) Wikipedia mentions this although in different articles.